# location.reload does not release memory in Internet Explorer 9 and higher

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-9

I have a website which is running 24/7 and is having some sort of memory leak.

While I am trying to fix the actual leak (which is difficult because I use a lot of 3rd party libraries), I wanted to solve this in the meantime by triggering a refresh (location.reload()) every hour. The problem is that not all memory is released and the used memory of Internet Explorer is still constantly increasing up to over a 1GB withing 24hours until it crashes.

I know that there are leaks in IE8 and below which don't get released until the browser is closed, but is this even true for IE9, 10 and 11 (because they all show the same behaviour)? The site uses a lot of Javascript and is quite "demanding" for the CPU, could it be that the browser doesn't have "time" to clean up properly?

I use iframes, a lot of ajax, bing maps and bit of canvas (and toDataURL) on the site. Could any of these technologies be responsible?